# Should my Gaillardia be emerging by now, in Zone 6?

Tags: growth, perennials

I live in Massachusetts, Zone 6. Last July I bought a beautiful [Gaillardia Arizona Sun](http://www.bluestoneperennials.com/GAAS.html). It bloomed all summer and into the fall. According to what I was told, as well as my online research, it's a perennial, however, there's no evidence of it so far this year.

Most of my perennials, including hostas, lilies, iris, dianthus, peonies, and others, are showing foliage. Some are even budding or blooming. Is it too soon to expect to see at least something emerging, or should I assume the Gaillardia died over the winter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have expected it to be showing some life by now - I've never yet managed to get a Gaillardia through a winter, but then I've got heavy soil - it does not like heavy soil and particularly hates being in wet/damp soil during winter, so if your soil conditions aren't light, sandy and very free draining, this might not be a plant for your garden.

Comment: In that part of the yard the soil is medium/heavy, and we had record breaking wet conditions this past winter, so I guess the poor thing never had a chance! Bearing in mind what you've taught me, it doesn't make sense to try again. Marigolds and other annuals did very well in that area, so I guess I'll stick to those this year!

Comment: Shame though - I tried several times because they're attractive, but never had any luck.